# Validating user answer

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to validate the answer from user. What i need to validate is if the user has given an answer that has the length of 7 which is of 3 uppercase letters followed by 4 numbers which have to be from 1000 to 9999 for example ACS1234. This has to be done using only javascript, no html.

```
var course1 = prompt('Enter Course Code')
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Comment: what have you tried on the validate part?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a regex? for example:

```js
var input = 'abc1234'; // get the user input
if (!input || !input.length === 7) { 
 //code for invalid
   return;
}
var matches = 'abd1234'.match(/([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4})/g);
if(matches && matches.length){ 
  // code for when valid
} else {
 // code for invalid
}
```

short explanation: check if there is a input at all, then check if it has a total length of 7. If if passes that test then use a regex to see if the first 3 characters are a letter and the last 4 characters digits